# Make list within another app

Tags: android

I did listview tutorial. I can't see how to integrate the list making program into another program I have.

I want to fill an array with sensor input values in one method of my public class, and then display the array as a list after that.

Is it possible to call the list making code as a function, in response to some user activity within the 'sensor' method? How do I do this?

Excuse me if this is stupid, I am a beginner to Java.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: do you mean integrating the list to an array in your application, then display it on another activity based on what you choose to be displayed?

Comment: Yes, that would do what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the way you construct a listview is via `List<? extends Map<String, ?>>`.
if you do want to construct it this way, here's how to do it.

fill the data inside a `List<Map<String,?>>`, then use a `SimpleAdapter` (or other adapter) to concatenate the list to `ListView`. suppose you have a `List<Map<String,?>>` named `mList`,

```
ListView mListView = (ListView)findViewById( --listView id-- );
String[] mFrom = { -key1-, -key2- };
int[] mTo = {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

SimpleAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, mFrom, mTo);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

`listView id` is the id of the listview on the xml, `key1` and `key2` respectively are the data you want to input inside the listview. however this one used android's default feature of list.

if you want to use your own listview template (i.e. you have more than 2 data inside),
  define the xml of your custom listview (customlist.xml) then change the `mTo` variable to match your textviews

```
int[] mTo = {R.id.-listTextView1-,R.id.-listTextView2-,R.id.-listTextView3-};
```

and point to that xml on this line

```
SimpleAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mList, R.layout.--customlistname--, mFrom, mTo);
```

Comment: from there you can easily call the ListView by its ID in any activity.